# Jquery - toggle current list item (100% width) and push items on left and right (if any) down

Tags: css, jquery

I have a <ul> with many <li> items. The <li>'s are displayed in tiled format (with the current CSS, 3 items fit in one row) and each <li> displays a brief intro and will expand (to 100% width) to show all info with onclick.
What I wanted but don't know how to is when an item is expanded, it takes the whole width of the page and **pushes items on the left and right down**. With the code I have so far (below), item 1, 4, 7... (the first of the row) works fine, but not 2, 3, 5, 6. Is there a way in jquery or CSS to do this? Or another way to look at it: is there a way to make the ***current*** item become the first of that row? Thanks!

```
<ul class="resutls">
<li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li><li>Item 4</li><li>Item 5</li> ...
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.results li {width:200px; height:140px; margin:7px 14px 7px 0; float:left;}
.results li.current{width:660px; height:auto;}
```

Jquery

```
 $('li').toggle(function() {  
   $(this).addClass("current");
   $($(this).find('.js-toggleContent')).toggle("slow");
 }, function() {  
   $(this).removeClass("current");
   $($(this).find('.js-toggleContent')).toggle("slow");   
 });
```

Comment: You have to re-write the HTML to change the order of the list items. CSS cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

I have something that will take a cell that is selected and pop it to a row directly above the row that contains it, making it full-width. Is that close to what you're looking for?  If so, you're going to need a mix of CSS and JS along with modifying your HTML to accommodate this.  Having done this very thing quite a few times (and having to redo it to meet client/customer expectations) this is what I often do. Have a look at it in this fiddle  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rdillman/4wZPU/)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="results">
    <div class="detail hide"></div>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="results">
    <div class="detail hide"></div>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="results">
    <div class="detail hide"></div>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.results{
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
    overflow: visible;
    width:652px;
    display:block;
    list-style: none;
}
.results li {
    background-color:red;
    padding: 0;
    width:200px;
    height:140px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:7px;
    list-style-type: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all .5s linear;
    -o-transition: all .5s linear;
    transition: all .5s linear;
}
.detail{
    background-color:orange;
    padding: 7px;
    width:624px;
    position:relative;
    top:7;
    visibility:visible;
    left:auto;
    opacity: 1;
    margin:0 7px 7px 7px;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
.hide{
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position:absolute;
}
.fade{
    opacity: .2;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    var $getDetails = $('.results div'),
          $getLis = $('.results li');
    $('.results').on('click', 'li', function() {
        $getLis.removeClass('fade');
        $getDetails.addClass('hide').empty();
        $(this).siblings('div')
            .html($(this).html())
            .addClass('hide')
            .removeClass('hide');
        $(this).addClass('fade');
    });
    $('.results').on('click', '.detail', function() {
        $getDetails.addClass('hide').empty();
        $getLis.removeClass('fade');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Richard. From the look and behavior perspective, that's pretty close. I can gray out the current item, and the result should be good. The only downsize is my list is pretty long and change frequently, adding additional ul and div may not be ideal.

Comment: I've been playing with this idea, not sure how to do yet, and not sure if it makes any sense: using jquery to add a ".group" to the (3n+1) elements, also using jquery to detect the current item in relation to the current li .group, then detach all 3 li belonging to that group, then reinsert and move the current item to the first of that group

Comment: Would not be that hard to do, but might be a funky user experience.  Grow one to full width and put it back at the front of the list, not where they got it from.  If that is the road you go down, you can in your results click function: var $copy = $(this).siblings('div').clone();$(this).siblings('div').remove();
$copy.prepend($(this).parent();